# Reading JSON date

Tags: json, timestamp

I have exported data from a health app showing my weight that I tracked over the last few years. The app no longer has this functionality so the only way for me to get this data is to read the JSON file and put it into another app. I understand the weight part, as it is KG, instead of LB. I just need help understanding the "Created_at" so I know what date this is from. Is there an easier way to translate this part of the JSON? Based on the timezone offset, it looks like it is in seconds, but that's all I have figured out so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
{
    "start_time": 1517323800000,
    "created_at": 1517323824000,
    "updated_at": 1517323824000,
    "start_time_timezone_offset": -22000,
    "weight": 73.84483783600001,
    "origin_type": "manual",
    "id": "d1640b9b-c8bd-6b54-5a3c-da492e8ac75a"
}
```

Comment: If `1517323800000` makes sense in being `2018-01-30T14:50:24+00:00` (without taking account of the timezone offset), it's a unix time stamp in milliseconds. You can check there: unixtimestamp.com

Answer (score 1):

Milliseconds to date converter helps you to find the date and time from a given total number of milliseconds. This total number of milliseconds is the elapsed milliseconds since timestamp or unix epoch counting from 1 January 1970.

for example: 1517323800000 is Tue 30 January 2018
16:50:00

https://www.timecalculator.net/milliseconds-to-date